# Sort a JSON response by descending order and keep only some values

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I'm facing an issue when I want to a specific attribute in my JSON response (structure below) 
[image]

I have to sort the results on the `percentage_match` by descending order but once it's done I need to put in an array the 5 first best results with the highest percentage match. This array has to contain the a maximum of the 5 best  `babylon_ref`. 
For example in the case below it would be : `[10170,20987,10187,9771,10387]`

I don't know how to deal with 2 values at the same time : sorting one and pushing another in an array. 
Is anyone has an idea of how to deal with this case in typescript ? 
Thank you

Comment: I rewrote my answer after realizing I didn't read the question carefully, let me know if you still need more information. But for me (in the jsfiddle attached) it's returning the answer/format you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Drill down to the tableDataList you want to work with
processedData = ...tableDataList.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.percentage_match - a.percentage_match;
}).slice(0, 5).map(resultObj => resultObj.babylon_ref);
```

[I used this jsfiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/0h2twxy3/17/)

Comment: Please explain the algorithm, it's not obvious at all a) how it is supposed to filter only some values, b) how it uses the fact that sorting is performed by one field and collected item is another field.

Comment: You are correct. I reread the question and I have no idea what I read the other day that made me misread it so badly. Thanks for calling me out.

Comment: I rewrote it now to what I believe to be what was asked